# Fit statistics and imputed data

Tags: sas, likelihood-ratio, multiple-imputation

I have a general question about pooling fit statistics when using multiple imputations. I am trying to pool the AIC, BIC, G-squared, or log likelihood across 10 imputed data sets. Is it possible to average these stats like you would the parameter estimates?

I tried to read this paper:
Meng, X. L., & Rubin, D. B. (1992). Performing likelihood ratio tests with multiply-imputed data sets. Biometrika, 79(1), 103-111.

But to be perfectly honest, I don't a firm enough grasp on the math to understand what they are saying they did with the log likelihood ratio.

Now before you tell me to use a program to pool the results, I've tried and cannot. So here are the specifics of what I am doing in case there is something I am doing wrong.

I am running a latent transition analysis (LTA) model using PROC LTA in SAS. (LTA is basically a longitudinal latent class analysis). I imputed the dataset using PROC MI and ran the model with PROC LTA, saving the estimates. The estimates saved include parameter estimates and the following fit statistics: log likelihood, degrees of freedom, G squared, AIC, BIC, Constant AIC, and Adjusted BIC. Since this doesn't include standard errors or the covariance matrix, I cannot use PROC MIANALYZE, as I get error messages requiring either the standard errors or covariance.

I tried to use STDERR to save the standard errors but it can only be used with PROC LCA.

The User's Guide can be accessed here, but I think you may need a login to actually download the PDF (though its free to sign up): http://methodology.psu.edu/downloads/proclcalta

Can anyone help me? If I can just average fit statistics, then I will just do that. If I can't and there is something I am overlooking using PROC MIANALYZE, I would greatly appreciate any help. I am completely stuck here and have gotten to the end of my statistical knowledge.